# Unable to Redirect After Log-in - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest

My app uses Identity Server authentication to login successfully. The problem I'm facing is that after login, the application does not redirect even after adding the redirect to the AuthorizationTokenRequest. Anyone had this issue before?

PS. The package I'm using to connect to identity server is called [flutter_appauth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth)

Dart:

```
Future<String> Authenticate() async {
    final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
        await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
            AutorizationTokenRequest(
                'flutter', 'com.michaelrademeyer.neuroagent://oauth2callback',
                discoveryUrl: '10.0.0.16:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration',
                scopes: [
                    'openid',
                    'profile',
                    'offline_access',
                    'neuroagentapi'
                ], allowInsecureConnections: true
            ),
        ) as AuthorizationTokenResponse;
        
        return result.accessToken as String;
}
```

Android Manifest File:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.michaelrademeyer.neuroagent"
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    manifestPlaceholders += [
        'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.michaelrademeyer.neuroagent'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @H.Rahimy Nope, i just switched to firebase

Comment: I did log an issue on github and someone came with a solution. dont know if it will suit you though. here it is: https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth/issues/335#issuecomment-1297776482